# UIScrollView not scrolling although contentSize is smaller than UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

So I have a `UIImageView` as a subview of `UIScrollView`, I've set the `contentSize` to be smaller than the `UIImageView` width and height, however it doesn't allow me to scroll.. why is this? Here's some code:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                //[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
                [imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [imgView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
                [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];

                CGRect imgFrame;
                imgFrame.size.width = originalImageSize.width;
                imgFrame.size.height = originalImageSize.height;
                imgFrame.origin.x = imageOriginPoint.x;
                imgFrame.origin.y = imageOriginPoint.y;

                UIScrollView * imgScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:imgFrame];
                [imgScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
                [imgScrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];
                [imgScrollView addSubview:imgView];
                [imgScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


  [imgScrollView setFrame:imgFrame];
                [imgScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];

SCROLL VIEW CONTENT SIZE WIDTH IS 200.000000 AND HEIGHT CONTENT SIZE IS 200.000000
UIIMAGE VIEW WIDTH IS 2240.225830 AND HEIGHT IS 2240.225830
SCROLL VIEW FRAME WIDTH IS 768.000000 AND SCROLL VIEW FRAME HEIGHT IS 768.000061
```

Any idea?

Comment: try this...imgScrollView.contentSize = imgView.frame.size;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because that your size of bounds of scroll view is larger than your content size.
The content size need to be the actual size of image view, and the visible size is set by frame / bounds. I guess you want to scroll a image in a {200, 200} sized rect?
Try this:

```
        UIScrollView * imgScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)]; // this is your visible rect
        [imgScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [imgScrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [imgScrollView addSubview:imgView];
        [imgScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

        [imgScrollView setContentSize:imgFrame.size]; // this is your image view size
```

Comment: so the frame size has to be smaller than the contentSize? if the frame size is the same as the contentSize then it won't scroll?

Comment: By default, YES. But if you set alwaysBounceVertical and alwaysBounceHorizontal to YES (both default NO), you can drag your content view even the contentSize is smaller than frame size

Comment: It was driving me nuts coz the scrollview was not scrolling when contentSize was less than the bounds' size. In my case, I want to reduce the content size of scrollview when keyboard comes up, I was amazed to see that reducing content size does not make the scroll view to scroll. Guess, I have to change the frame of the scroll view instead.

Answer (score 11):

the janky way to do this is to always set the contentSize to be larger than the view size. But there's a property in Swift that allows a scrollview to always "scroll" regardless of the content size:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

There's one for horizontal scrolling as well

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I want to point out that when you create a `UIScrollView` in code the most important thing to set is:

`scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;`

If you don't set that, your `contentSize` is irrelevant.

Comment: This is much better suited to being a comment, rather than an answer. In any case it is misleading: as [stated in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollEnabled), the default value for `scrollEnabled` is `YES`. You **do not** need to set `scrollEnabled` to `YES` in code, unless you have previously set it to `NO`.

Comment: I disagree.  It works as an answer also.  (And it just solved my problem. Thanks Chris.) A lot of people scroll down looking at the answers, and don't read all (or any) of the comments unless the answer leads them to.  Sometimes you're working with code written by another and you may not be familiar with it all.

Comment: I had to set mine to YES to get it to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

scroll view content size should be more than scrollView frame width and height
do this -

```
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(originalImageSize.width,originalImageSize.height);
```

I think it will help.

Comment: It will not allow to scroll, if you want scroller to scroll , content size should be more than frame size

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set this using IB then make sure your UIScrollView's Height property is set to lower number than your contentView's Height property. For example, if you've set the height of your contentView to 810 pts make sure to set your UIScrollView's height to something like 610 pts or so.