# UIScrollView - unable to scroll very far down (even though I have set contentsize to 1000)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I would like to use scroll view to display about 20 lines of text, with a button at the very bottom.

However, when I run my app, the page will not scroll down to the bottom of the page where the button is.

I have tried changing the content size height, but it does not change the scroll view at all.

I am running Xcode 4.6.

```
//.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScroller;


//.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.theScroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320.0,1000.0);
[super viewDidLoad] }
```

Any ideas why I can only scroll down half the page?
Is there a better way to display the 20 lines of text + button?

Edit - My current frame rectangle is 310W, 500H
Edit - To be clear, I can scroll down the page, but I cannot scroll all the way to the bottom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the frame of your content?

Comment: At the moment I have the "Frame Rectangle" set to 320W, 1000H (no idea if this was the right thing to do though, it is the first time I have used Scroll View).

Comment: The frame rectangle of your scroll view must  be smaller than the contentSize. The frame is where the scroll view resides within its superview's boundaries, and the contentSize is the size of the content that is displayed inside the scroll view itself.

Comment: what is the frame of your scroll view?

Comment: I had tried your code & it works fine. What is the frame of your scroll view?

Comment: Thanks pe60t0, I have set the frame rectangle to 310W, 500H.
I still cannot scroll down to the bottom though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889696/uiscrollview-not-scrolling-although-contentsize-is-smaller-than-uiimageview  please try this answer

Comment: are you running app on iPhone5?

Comment: have you added self.theScroller.ScrollEnabled = YES; ? does it already scroll ?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running app in iPhone5 problem may be due to the scrollview frame. Here you are setting scrollView frame height to 500 pix, ie height greater than device view. Try by reducing the size less than 480. let's use 300 for now